# Can one reset button clear both the input and the result?

Tags: html, forms

I have built a form in HTML and it is working as I like it, except the reset button.

I would like one reset button that clears all the user input and the verdict. This clears the input but leaves the verdit.

I have been looking all over online but can't find how to do this. Here is my code:

```
<form name="myform">

    <table border="5px solid" border-color= "black #444 #888 #ccc" width="50%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table-striped" style="margin-right: calc(25%); margin-left: 10px width: 80%;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 92.7258%;">
                    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;Enter the estimate &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$
                    <input maxlength="10" size="5" name="b" value="">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;The amount from the letter &nbsp;$
                    <input maxlength="10" size="5" name="c" value="">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;The number of months, enter 12 for a full year.&nbsp;
                    <input maxlength="2" size="5" name="d" value="">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;Enter the quote amount.&nbsp;$
                    <input maxlength="10" size="5" name="e" value="">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <p></p>
                  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input onclick="perc1()" type="button" value="Calculate">&nbsp; &nbsp;
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset">
                    
                    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp; <div id="verdict">
                    <br> 
                </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

The verdict is like a paragraph long and I couldn't figure out how to send something that long to another input. That's why the div id and the subsequent problem.

Thanks for your guidance! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<div>` dedicated to verdict is not part of the form fields so it is not cleared by the reset button.

You can add an `onreset` function to the form tag and define a JavaScript function to reset the form and verdict.

```html
<form name="myform" onreset="resetForm()">
```

and function

```js
function resetForm() {
    // Clear input values
    document.myform.b.value = '';
    document.myform.c.value = '';
    document.myform.d.value = '';
    document.myform.e.value = '';
    
    // Clear verdict
    document.getElementById('verdict').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Flerken! That worked perfectly. I appreciate the solution and the education. Hope you have a great week! =D